# Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined // can't get the date in ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, get

Can't load my data, i guess something is wrong with getting the date. Here's my ajax:

```
function refreshdata(page) {

dates = '{ "date": "2017-05-12T09:14:15Z" }';

if (page == 1) {

    $.ajax({
        url: semRoute, 
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) {
            var data = JSON.parse(result);
            showData(data);
        }

    });

}

console.log(page);
```

}

AjaxController:

```
 public string Get(string date)
    {
        var obj = new DepDate(date);
        return Model.balance.GetDataJSON(obj);
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried to provide `data: dates` setting in AJAX call? What do you get with `result` (use `console.log(result)` to see it)?

Comment: @Tetsuya, i tried to provide data this way. In console.log i get this error: `jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 GET http://localhost/api/BalanceAjax?{%20%22date%22:%20%222019-01-11T18:25:43.511Z%22%20} 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Try setting `contentType: "application/json"` because you're passing JSON string instead of date object in AJAX call. Make sure that `date` contains ISO-formatted date value afterwards.